# Drag and drop in Praat: If we want to develop this function, what to do?

Tags: javascript, windows, macos, plugins, praat

Praat is open-source a phonetics analysis software. We constantly need to drag files into the software. While it has a drag-and-drop function for the Mac version, it does not have it for windows. This is a headache and I'm trying to find some solutions.

I understand there must be reasons behind this and I do not doubt the developers at all. But just out of curiosity for the general software developing knowledge, I was wondering:

1. Is it different for Mac and Windows? Is it easier to develop this function on MacOS?
2. If we want this function for Windows, is there a plug-in or something that we can use? If not, then what do we need to do to realise this?
   I know a friend who wrote a program 10 years ago to enable dragging and dropping files to upload to a website. Would having such a script (maybe in js or html5) help with developing this function in other exes such as Praat? Is there a language that seems to be the most suitable for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware that praat under mac has this function.

Also the code in javascript/php that you mentioned won't help because praat is a mix of objective c, c and c++.

No plugin would work you'd have to work on the source code here
https://github.com/praat/praat